# Autoload function in my vimrc

Tags: vim

I had a cool function in my `.vimrc` which allows me to complete the words with <kbd>tab</kbd>. Here it is :

```
" Tab completion of tags/keywords if not at the beginning of the line.
function! InsertTabWrapper()
  let col = col('.') - 1
   if !col || getline('.')[col - 1] !~ '\k'
      return "\<tab>"
   else
      return "\<c-p>"
   endif
endfunction
```

I mapped the tab with

```
inoremap <tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper()<cr>
```

But it doesn't work properly when I open a file, I need to source my `.vimrc` with

```
:source $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

to make it work.

**EDIT** :
Apparently there's a conflict with *SnipMate* plugin

```
<Tab> * <C-R>=TriggerSnippet()<CR>
Last set from ~/.vim/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
```

Is there a way to use Tab for both ?

Comment: Try `:verbose imap <tab>` to see if `<tab>` is remapped and where.

Comment: @romainl returns No mapping found - I edited the question with other tab mappings btw

Comment: Just to be sure, is it `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: yep, it's in my home directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your `.vimrc` wasn't sourced, or the mapping wasn't reached (conditional? `:finish` somewhere?). You can check which scripts were loaded with `:scriptnames`; it should list the full path to your `.vimrc`. Also look for modifications to `'runtimepath'`. You can debug the initial execution command by command by starting Vim via `vim -V15`.

In any case, you can check whether the mapping is there through `:verbose imap <Tab>`

Comment: Thx for your answer. There's a conflit with snipmate apparently : `i  <Tab>       * <C-R>=TriggerSnippet()<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/after/plugin/snipMate.vim`

Comment: Huh? You mentioned _No mapping found_ earlier. Anyway, you have to decide between snipMate and your mapping, and choose a different key sequence for one of them. Though you could modify your mapping to fall back to snipMate; replace `return "\<tab>"` with `return TriggerSnippet()`

Comment: ok - i remap the InsertTabWrapper() to <C-@>, it's better than nothing. The `return TriggerSnippet()` don't seems to work